# How do I add the contact form to a CMS page in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, contact-form

Is this really as complicated a process as I'm seeing in the few tutorials I've found? How do I add the contact form to a CMS page in Prestashop?

Comment: Your answer is closed but you can find some help form here. http://www.vipulhadiya.com/how-to-use-wordpress-plugins-in-prestashop/